# If $\sigma(n)$ denote the sum of all the divisors of $n$, then $\sigma(2^93^2)$ is divisible by?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I came across a question today...

> Let $\sigma(n)$ denote the sum of all the divisors of $n$, then $\sigma(2^93^2)$ is divisible by
>
> (a) 3
> (b) 11
> (c) 13
> (d) 31

I tried to make a small list of numbers in Geometric Progression which are divide $2^93^2$. These GP's are...
$$1+2+2^2+....+2^9$$ and $$3+3 \times 2+3 \times 2^2+....+3 \times 2^9$$ and $$9+9 \times 2+9 \times 2^2+....+9 \times 2^9$$

The sum of first, second and third GP's are $511$, $3 \times 511$ and $9 \times 511$. Summing all these three up, we get $6643$. And it is divisible by $13$. But it's not the answer. Answer is

> All the four options.

What was my mistake? Why my solution is wrong?

Comment: $2^9=512$ so the $1+2+\dots+2^9=1023$ not $511$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is fine. But $1+2+\dots+2^9=2^{10}-1=1023$ not 511.

Answer (score 1):

By your method, the sum is $(1+3+3^2)(1+2+2^2+\cdots+2^9)=13\cdot 1023$, then by factorizing $1023$ you will find all options are answers.